# Simple ajaxify, without hash or hashbang urls

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, url, hashbang

I'm taking a course in webdesign. I and a lot of the other students are really interested in ajaxifying our work. Our teacher is only into design and HTML - so he can't help.

I hope I use the right term - otherwise please correct me. By ajaxifying, I mean having my webpage only update certain parts when navigating.

For example, let's say I have a webpage consisting of 3 subpages:

1: **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Welcome! </title></head>
<body>
    <div id="Content"> Welcome, dear visitor... take a look around! </div>
    <div id="Menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><b> Home </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html"> Projects </a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"> Email and mediaplayer </div>  
</body></html>
```

2: **projects.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Projects </title></head>
<body>
    <div id="Content"> All my projects are shown here! </div>
    <div id="Menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html"><b> Projects </b></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"> Email and mediaplayer </div>  
</body></html>
```

3: **contact.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Contact </title></head>
<body>
    <div id="Content"> Contact info! </div>
    <div id="Menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html"> Projects </a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"><b> Contact </b></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"> Email and mediaplayer </div>  
</body></html>
```

When using the links:

- Only the Content-div should be reloaded.
- The Menu should update which menu-point is active (here shown with bold-tags). If that's too complex a reload of the menu could work.
- The Footer should not be reloaded at all.
- The title should be updated.
- The url should be updated.
- I would really like the urls to be clean. That is: NOT **/#projects.html** or **/#/projects.html**, but just straight-up **/projects.html** or **/projects**
- Working bookmarking and back-button are crucial.

Is this possible at all? I would be forever insanely thankful to anyone helping me here! :-D
I've tried out (and hacked around with) jQuery Address and History plugins, the [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) and a ['gist'](https://gist.github.com/854622) to it. Couldn't get any of it to work. I've trawled and trawled stack overflow and google, but can't seem to find anyone explaining these things or having a simple solution.

A solution aiming at modern webbrowsers would be fine. If the IE guys and the no javascripts guys just gets the simple html-version, that would be cool - but it's not absolutely necessary.

Please help - any help would be very, very appreciated! Thanx! :-)

Comment: How is it possible to load content via Ajax and expect the back-button or bookmarking to work? Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I guess these features are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the HTML5 History API - http://html5demos.com/history.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is possible, but not quite easy to do.
As already mentioned, the HTML5 History API makes it possible, but you will need a good knowledge of javascript. Displaying more or less static pages isn't exactly what it's intended for, but the sake of learning, let's think about how it could be done.

You might probably want to use a framework like [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) that already comes with a router so that you don't have to write your own abstractions.

The basic idea behind a client side router is that you have an easy way of defining what URL triggers what javascript function similar to this:

```
var routes = {
    "index": "open_index",
    "projects": "open_projects",
    "contact": "open_contact"
}

var open_index = function(){
    // Do the logic that has to be done
    // to open the index page
}

...
```

Note that the code is only there to illustrate the idea, it doesn't conform to any actual framework or library.

Anyway, every time that one of these routes is triggered you need to take care of basically taking apart the entire page and replacing everything with the desired content.

Now you have basically two choices for that. Either you fetch HTML from the server and just plug it in, or you only fetch the actual data in JSON and use client side templating.

What does that mean? Well, right now you use static HTML pages. They do have a basic structure that is shared by all the pages, namely the separation in 'Content', 'Menu' and 'Footer', however, since this is not a web application but a web site, the content of the 'Content' probably does not follow a structure that represents some kind of structured data.
An example for it representing structured data would be a phone directory. You always have a list of 'First name', 'Last name' , 'Phone number' and this is primarily what defines the page. The way it looks is not what the page is about.

The entire content of the page can be defined by an array like this:

```
var people = [
 { "firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Doe", "number": "+12-2322132"},
 { "firstName" : "Dick", "lastName" : "Dobson", "number": "+12-656533"},
 ...
]
```

and rendered client side using a simple template like for example:

```
<ul class="phone_book">
  {{#each people}}
  <li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}} - {{number}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

to generate the needed HTML. (That was [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) by the way)
Using a framework, you can easily set it up for the script to update the information display automatically upon updating the data - for example by using AJAX.

In your case however, it is most likely that the way the page looks is what it is about. You need one image here and one image there and a bit of text inbetween, and all of this changes with every single page. You need HTML.
That's the reason why what you want isn't exactly what you would use the History API and AJAX for. It is primarily intended for complex web applications that need to spread several pages with their own urls that can also potentially capture the state of the application so that linking to a specific part of a javascript heavy web application becomes possible. Loading static websites works just fine without using AJAX and the History API.

Let's ignore this right now and just continue anyway.
Let's try and see what the open_index function needs to work.

```
var open_index = function(){
    // 1. Fade out the old content and remove it
    // 2. Request the new html content from the server
    // 3. Mark the new active link in the navigation
    // 4. Add the content to the DOM
    // 5. Fade in the new content
}
```

All of this you can easily do with jQuery. You'll have no trouble finding an explanation for how to do this.

Now you are almost there. The only remaining thing to take care of is to make sure that you intercept the click events for your navigation so that you can use the History API and it won't just load the static page from the beginning.

For a simple use such as this, not a whole lot more is needed structure wise.

I'll say it again. This is complete overkill for your purpose and you should not be using it for that other than for learning purposes. If you don't use a library that abstracts away the History API a bit, the code will become a lot more complex.

I hope this helped giving you an idea of what you are dealing with.